# Last if statement always evaluating to true (overwriting)?

Tags: php

I'm trying to display an image based on a change in rank. If the values of the array `$rank_change` are echoed before my if statements, the correct values are printed, such as:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

However, if printed after the following if statements, `side.gif` is always shown:

```
if($rank_change[$i] > 0) { $rank_change[$i] = "<img src=\"up.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"/>"; }
if($rank_change[$i] < 0) { $rank_change[$i] = "<img src=\"down.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"/>"; }
if($rank_change[$i] == 0) { $rank_change[$i] = "<img src=\"side.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"/>";}
```

In the cases where the value of `$rank_change` are 7 and 1, why does the last statement still evaluate to true?

I realize it would be more efficient to use `switch($rank_change[$i])` but, I still don't understand why the final if statement is evaluating true on all values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an else-if instead of a simple if for the last two conditions.

you are actually overwriting the value in `$rank_change[$i]` in the expression following each test. `$rank_change[$i] = "<img src=\"up.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"/>"` will change the value of `$rank_change[$i]`, which will make one of the following test return true as well, resulting in another change of the value of `$rank_change[$i]`...

use an `else if` construct, and only one test will succeed.

Comment: Because, presumably, the comparison `"any string" == 0` evaluates to `true` in PHP?

Comment: I'll try that, but I still don't see why the last would always be tripped, as `if` statements are only meant to evaluate `true` if the condition is met, otherwise it's ignored - isn't that the case?

Comment: Ah, good explanation! I didn't think about that. Done, and of course, worked :). I'll accept your answer when the timer drops!

Comment: `"any string" == 0` evaluates to `true` in php: you compare a string and an integer, php will first try to convert the string into an integer. but `"any string"` does not represent any integer value, thus php assumes its 0. (i hate this language for those pesky string to integer conversions). [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) is the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Adrien is correct, you should use if-else statements. The last condition is evaluating to true because php is doing some type coercion on your values.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (specifically the types comparison table) for more information on when / how it does this.

Basically, it's changing `'derp' == 0` to `(int)'derp' == 0`. `(int)'derp'` is 0.